# What is wrong with this simple Golf Game Java code?

Tags: java, debugging

I'm lost. In my Java 1 class I'm supposed to debug this simple code and fix it. It's a simple Golf Game. I know this question is basically asking you guys too do my homework, but I want help getting pushed in the right direction for future debug assignments.

**GolfGame.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * Debugging Exercise - Chapter 4
 *
 * Debug the error(s) and submit to the Dropbox on Angel
 * Please do not submit if it is not debugged
 *
 */

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// READ ME FIRST:
//   This program compiles, but, there is logic error in the while statement.
//   Debug the logic error and run the program to calculate your golf score.
//   Try inputting several numbers to get the total score.
//   The program should keep looping until the user selects -1 to terminate.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class GolfGame {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void getTotalScore() {

        int score = 0, total = 0;

        while ( score == -1 )
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a score [-1 to quit]: ");
            score = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            total += score;
        }

        if (total != -1)
            System.out.println("Your total score is " + total);
    }
}
```

**GolfGameTest.java**

```
/*
 * This is the MAIN class; RUN this class to show
 * that the GolfGame.java program functions correctly.
 *
 * NOTE: You must first debug the GolfGame.java file.
 *       There is no need to debug this file.
 */
public class GolfGameTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Golf Game Calculator");
        GolfGame golfGame = new GolfGame();
        golfGame.getTotalScore();
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `while ( score != -1 )`

Comment: Please do not dump your assignments here. Show your work, explain where your stuck, ask *specific* questions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I wasn't asking for a answer, I was asking for a push in the right direction. I don't mean too just dump my homework on it. Thanks for the heads up, though.

Comment: @JordanSimps: All you need to do is to show a little more effort in asking thisquestion; it will go a long way. Show the work you've done and ask the more specific question. Otherwise questions similar to this will often be closed. Thanks for taking my criticism well.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void getTotalScore() {
int score = 0, total = 0;
    while ( score == -1 )
    /*** snip ***/
```

the while loop will never be entered.

A push in the right direction...review loop control.  If you are having trouble entering the loop, the next and much more painful defect is not far off, "infinite loop".

When coding a loop, the practice is to track the loop control variable, mentally or on paper over several iterations, ensuring that:

1. the loop is entered when it should be
2. the loop is exited when it should be
3. the loop control variable varies over iterations as it should

The reason for the above ordering is based on the percentage of times that failing to do so results in a defect.

Comment: Thank you. This is a perfect answer and I appreciate not actually giving me the answer. I don't understand why I got down rated, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If I could go back to when I started programming and teach myself only one thing it would be the basics of using a debugger.

It would really help you to learn the debugging features of netbeans.  It is probably the single most important thing you could do to get better at solving debugging problems.  I'd suggest learning the following to start:

1. Step In/Step Out/Step Over - learn how to slowly step through code line by line
2. Breakpoints - learn how to stop a program at a particular point so you can see if the program makes it to a certain line, and what the variable values are at that line.
3. Watching variables - see the value of a variable while debugging.
4. Googling - I just googled "Debugging in Netbeans" and came up with the following.  But sometimes it is hard to know what to google for :)

This looks like a good start to learn about debugging in NetBeans:

http://www.cs.uga.edu/~shoulami/sp2009/cs1301/tutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial.htm

In your example, you could step through the code and see that you never made it into the while loop.  You could also look at the value of the score variable (which would be 0) and see that the condition in "while ( score == -1 )" was not true.